# Copy pointer to struct to new pointer to copy of the struct in in C

Tags: c, pointers, copy

i have this case where i want to store pointers to structs in some hash table (linked list ) 
i have :

```
struct Base {
 int age;
};

struct Base *l1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Base )); 
l1->age = 20;
```

now here i stuck somewhere in the code (deep down)
i have function which gives me the pointer to Base

```
callback_(struct Base *l)
{
```

i don't want to point to l1 which will be gone when the callback ends
i want to create new pointer to base which the values of the l1 (age)

```
struct Base  *l2 = ???;
```

do i need to copy each value ? (deep copy ) 
in realty there are many members and allot of data so i need something better then deep copy

Comment: The first snippet is invalid code. YOu cannot have statements outside a function. How about providing a [mcve]? Makes things much clearer from the start.

Comment: can't its from very big lagacy code , i just present the general idea

Comment: I don't see why `*l1` is "gone when the callback ends". That's why a [mcve] is required imo. Smells like missunderstanding or an XY-problem.

Comment: You can very well. You are just too lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways how to manage such situation. You could either create new struct object inside the callback and perform the "flat" copy of the struct or write your own function to copy an object. This is analagous to leaving the implicit copy constructor or writing your own copy constructor in C++.

#### option 1:

```
callback_(struct Base *l)
{
    struct Base  *l2 = malloc(sizeof *l2);
    *l2 = *l;
    // ...
}
```

#### option 2:

```
struct copyBase* Base(struct Base* op)
{
    struct Base* this = malloc(sizeof *this);
    this->age = op->age;

    return this;
}
```

You can use it inside the callback like this:

```
callback_(struct Base *l)
{
    struct Base  *l2 = copyBase(l);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! for your help